# SSRS Null Hidden Parameter in SharePoint Integrated Mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report (call it Report A) that was built using only the User!UserId to generate appropriate data for that person.  This worked perfectly.

The feature was requested to be able to view other people's data through Report A, based upon security inside the underlying stored proc.  I updated Report A to include a new parameter, EmployeeId, and created a new front screen report that has a "Go To Report" action, passing the EmployeeId.  The Stored Proc takes both the UserId and EmployeeId, and returns the data for the requested employee, if the User has permission to see the data.  This also works perfectly.

I set the EmployeeId parameter to be hidden, and a default value of null.  This was to allow anyone who comes directly to Report A to be able to run for their data (no impersonation), as they are used to.  Running from within BIDS, it works, but once I publish to SharePoint, I get:

"The report is missing a parameter value but prompting for it has been disabled."

I obviously don't want to prompt for the parameter, and value should be null in this case.  Does SharePoint integrated mode not allow for hidden and null parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326410%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), it looks as though you may need to explicitly override the parameter value to set it to be null in the Manage Parameters dialog within the library/folder containing the report.

Comment: The Reporting Features weren't turned on in the SharePoint library (no "Manage Parameters" context menu), but once they were, following this fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

In SSRS 2008 with Sharepoint, you need to prefix each parameter passed in the URL with "rp:". For example: URL.../RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/TestReports/Orders.rdl&rs:Command=Render&rp:CLordID=1324381